# Running for loop inside other for loop

Tags: php, html, for-loop

Can anyone help me understand why a variable takes its initial value after incrementing the variable? below is code:

```php
$k= 0;
$l= 3;
for($i = 0; $i<3; $i++){
    for($j = $k; $j<$l; $j++){
        echo $j;
    }
    echo $k+3;
    echo $l+3;
}
```

In this we have two for loops running one inside other. Here we run three times the outside for loop, inside this we are running other for loop again. The problem we are facing is that when inner for loop end we have incremented `$k` and `$l` both by 3 but it always take value 0 and 3 respectively.

Comment: Do you to increment `$k` and `$l` every time while iterating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> we have incremented $k and $l both by 3

Nope, you only print the result of your values plus 3, but you do not set them anywhere in the loop:

Instead of

```
echo $k+3;  
echo $l+3;
```

write

```
$k = $k + 3;
$l = $l + 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try removing the "echo" and incrementing the variable in each loop. Then print them out after.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <?php
$k= 0;
$l= 3;
for($i = 0; $i<3; $i++){
    for($j = $k; $j<$l; $j++){
        $j = $j++;
    }
    $k = $k+3;
    $l = $l+3;
}

echo $k.'<br>';
echo $l;
?>
```

Gives you:

9
12

Answer (score 0):

TRY this.
$k += 3; 
$l += 3;

echo $k;
echo $l;

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$k= 0;
$l= 3;
for($i = 0; $i<3; $i++){
    for($j = $k; $j<$l; $j++){
        echo $j;
    }
    $k = $k+3;
    $l = $l+3;
}
echo $k.'<br>';
echo $l;
```

First Increment the value and store it in the variable

```
$k = $k+3;
$l = $l+3;
```

Then You need to print using

```
echo $k.'<br>';
echo $l;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Harinarayan First of all you need to read about echo() http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

> echo — Output one or more strings

echo does not manipulate expression as you did in your question like:

> echo $k+3;

instead of using echo for the increment you should first increment the variable and then echo that variable like below:

```
<?php
  $k= 0;
  $l= 3;
  for($i = 0; $i<3; $i++){
      for($j = $k; $j<$l; $j++){
          echo $j;
      }
      $k += 3;
      $l += 3;
      echo $k;
      echo "<br>";
      echo $l;
  }
```